# Errors when modifying a dictionary in python

Tags: python

Suppose I want to create a dictionary that maps digits to numbers less than 100 ending in those digits as follows:

```
d = {}
for i in range(100):
 r = i % 10
 if r in d:
  d[r] = d[r].append(i)
 else:
  d[r] = [i]
print d
```

First of all, when i is 20, d[r] is apparently a NoneType when I try to append to it, throwing an error.  Why would this be?  Secondly, I feel like my approach is inefficient, as the work in checking if r in d isn't propagated.  Something like this would be better, I feel:

```
case(d[r]) of 
   SOME(L) => d[r] = L.append(i)
 | NONE => d[r] = [i]
```

Is there a way to have that logic in python?

Comment: `d[r] = d[r].append(i)` should be `d[r].append(i)`. `list.append` modifies the list, and does not return the new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, when i is 20, d[r] is apparently a NoneType when I try to append to it, throwing an error. Why would this be?

This is because the following code is wrong:

```
d[r] = d[r].append(i)
```

`.append` modifies the list *as a side effect*, and returns `None`. So after the list is appended to, it gets thrown away and replaced with the `None` value now being re-assigned into `d[r]`.

> Is there a way to have that logic in python?

There are a variety of hacks that can be used, but none of them are appropriate here.

Instead, solve the specific problem: "modify a dictionary value if present, or create a new value otherwise". This can be refined into "create an empty default value if absent, and then modify the value now guaranteed to be present".

You can do that using `.setdefault`, or more elegantly, you can replace the dictionary with a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(100):
    r = i % 10
    d[r].append(i)
```

Or you can solve the even more specific problem: "create a dictionary with a given pattern", i.e. from applying a rule or formula to an input sequence (in this case, the input is `range(100)`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def last_digit(i): return i % 10
d = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(range(100), key=last_digit), last_digit)}
```

Or you can solve the even more specific problem, by taking advantage of the fact that `range` takes another argument to specify a step size:

```
d = {i: range(i, 100, 10) for i in range(10)}
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions are only in Python 3, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

With Andrew's suggestion to use `d[r].append(i)`, you get the desired answer:

```
In [3]: d
Out[3]: 
{0: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
 1: [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91],
 2: [2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92],
 3: [3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73, 83, 93],
 4: [4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94],
 5: [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95],
 6: [6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96],
 7: [7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, 97],
 8: [8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98],
 9: [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99]}
```

You could do this:

```
In [7]: for onesdigit in range(10):
   ...:     d[onesdigit] = range(onesdigit, 100, 10)
```